Is it possible to access the DB in the phone from the Laptop?
I successfully created and filled a DB from a sample app using Flutter on an Android device.
Now, can I access this DB from outside the app, ideally from the Laptop I'm using for the development?
Thank you!

Would https://docs.objectbox.io/data-browser help?
